# Can a CS grad student work on quantum field theory and string theory problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing

The mathematical aspect of particle physics theory are interesting and there seems to be a lot more connections being made to computation and information (like with complexity theory having some impact of physics and the whole quantum computation thing). Does it make sense (or is even possible) to work on some of these connections as a grad student in a theoretical computer science department or should I be looking at mathematical physics programs instead?

My main concern is with finding advisors and departments that are game for something like this (given that this makes any sense in the first place).

Comment: Is there any reason you're asking this question here and the other two on cstheory?

Comment: You would have to ask potential advisors about that. Identify the corpus of work that interests you (e.g. via Google Scholar) and check out the authors.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of computer scientists working on quantum computation and quantum information so, yes, there should be plenty of opportunities to work on that sort of thing as a CS grad student.

I'm not aware of any computer scientists working on string theory but it's far from my area of expertise so it's possible it happens without my knowing about it. However, I've been to plenty of theoretical CS conferences where there were a couple of talks about quantum things but I don't remember any talks at all about string theory. And, of course, if you try to Google for something like "string theory computer science", Google thinks you mean strings of text.